# Cannot update model after adding stored procedures to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a **MVC 4** application. 
Using **Entity Framework Database First design paradigm**. 
My database is in **mySQL, on a remote server**. 
I am using the **mysql connector 6.6.5**. 
I am using **Visual Studio 2012 with updates installed just two days ago**.

**The problem**: I created my tables and then generated the model. After that I created some stored procedures and then updated my model by rightclicking the model diagram and then selecting "Update Model from Database"

In the next dialouge box I then select my new stored procedure. But some stored procedures are not being generated in my model. (I cannot see them under Function Imports in the Model Browser.). Even if I generate the model one more time, no success.

For stored procedure I get this error when generating model:

**An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occured while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is 'No data - zero rows fetched, selected or processed'.**

Funny thing is I tested the stored procedure from MySQL workbench. The stored procedure works as expected.

Please help!

Comment: It's a bug in your MySQL EF provider.

Comment: thanks! i think so too. Morover I found out another thing...Visual Studio cannot generated stored procedures containing cursors. I rewrote the stored procedure without cursors and the error message dissappeared.